# How can the pressure of the gas and that on the piston be different?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure

In the book of Kondepudi & Prigogine, Modern Theormodynamics, at page 114, it is stated that

> In a reversible expansion of a gas, **the pressure of the gas and that
>   on the piston are assumed to be the same**. If we consider an isothermal
>   expansion of a gas that has a constant temperature T by virtue of its
>   contact with a heat reservoir, the change in entropy of the gas deS =
>   dQ/T, in which dQ is the heat flow from the reservoir to the gas that
>   is necessary to maintain the temperature constant. This is an ideal
>   situation. In any real expansion of a gas that takes place in a finite
>   time, the pressure of the gas is greater than that on the piston.

and they go on showing what happened when they are not equal.

However, I'm having trouble understanding how can such a thing even possible ?

I mean, by definition, the pressure on the piston is the pressure applied on the piston by the gas (it is not like the piston has its own internal pressure or something), so how can a gas apply a lower pressure than its own pressure to an external object. I mean, as far as I know, the way how we measure the pressure of a gas is by means of such an external object, so it really does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Which “thing” are you having trouble understanding, the quoted statement or what happens when the pressures aren’t equal?

Comment: @BobD I'm having trouble in understanding how can those two values be different.

Comment: In that case you need to tell us what the author went on to say so that we can see the context

Comment: Suppose there are reservoirs of gas on both sides of the piston, but at very different pressures.

Comment: Are you familiar with Newton's 3rd law of action-reaction which says that the force exerted by B on A is *equal in magnitude* and opposite in direction to the force which A exerts on B.

Comment: The piston is a solid that can have compressive stress within it.  You are familiar with the 3D  version of Hooke's law involving stresses and strains, right?  At the inner surface of the piston, the compressive stress in the piston is equal in magnitude to the compressive stress (i.e., the pressure) in the gas.

Comment: @ChetMiller If I understand you correctly, you are saying the same thing as me, and this contradicts with what the authors are saying in the book.

Comment: @gandalf61 so ? the pressure on each side of the piston are different, but still, for each side, the pressure on that side and the pressure of the gas on that side are equal.

Comment: I guess we must not be understanding each other, because I agree with what is stated in the book.  Yet, I also agree with what you said to gandalf61.  If the piston has mass (and the cylinder is vertical), the pressures on the two faces of the piston don't have to be equal.  But I think your book is referring to the piston pressure at the face in contact with the gas.

Comment: @ChetMiller See my edit, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the text refers to the pressure "on the piston" it clearly means the pressure applied to the *other face* of the piston. If the pressure applied to the *other face* of the piston were always exactly the same as the pressure of the gas then the piston would not move and there would be no expansion or compression of the gas. On the other hand, if we have a vacuum on the other face of the piston (and assume a light piston with no friction) then the gas will expand very rapidly, and this process is irreversible.

A reversible expansion is an ideal situation where the pressure on the piston is infinitesimally less than the pressure of the gas, so the piston moves at an infinitesimal speed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics).

Answer (score 1):

Your edit changes things considerably.  Now, instead of looking at a reversible expansion, you are looking at an irreversible expansion.  But, in the sense that you originally indicated, the authors are incorrect in saying that the gas pressure is higher than that exerted by the piston.  If, by pressure, they mean the force per unit area (normal stress) exerted by the gas on the piston face, then this is always  equal to the force per unit area that the piston exerts on the gas.  But, if they mean the pressure calculated from the ideal gas law $nRT/V$, this value will be higher than the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston and the piston on the gas.  The difference between these two views is related to the irreversible fluid dynamics behavior that is occurring.  In particular, it is related to the viscous behavior of the gas as it is deforming.  I can get into this in more detail if you would like, but I'm not sure you would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

If the piston in a cylinder is moving rapidly away from the gas, then the momentum transferred to the piston from each colliding gas molecule will be less, thus reducing the effective pressure.

Comment: "then the momentum transferred to the piston from each colliding gas molecule will be less": how ?